# Postgres cannot find my sequence

Tags: postgresql

Although there are answers to this on internet but somehow not working for me.

I want to manually change next value for my sequence. In pgAdmin, I can see the sequence **Substances_SUBID_seq** in the list under Sequences but following query is not working in **Query Tool** of **pgAdmin**

```
select setval('Substances_SUBID_seq', (select max("SUBID") from "Substances"));
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR:  relation "substances_subid_seq" does not exist 
LINE 1: select setval('Substances_SUBID_seq', (select max("SUBID") f...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see it as `Substances_SUBID_seq` exactly then you should specify the name in double quotes (double quotes inside single quotes)

```
'"Substances_SUBID_seq"'
```

That way postgresql does not lowercase it during execution (see the error message).